# Wifi router: Client connects and gets ip but can not connect to any computer after that

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a pretty standard network at home with a wifi router and some devices connected via LAN and some connected via Wifi. The router is an Asus RT AC68U. For some days now I can not use my Wifi anymore. The wired devices still work. If I connect to the router via Wifi it connects and gets an IP from the DCHP server (which is a different one than the router) and after that there is no way to connect with any device in the network not even using the IP. After that I can't even reach the gateway. Still the router recognizes the wifi connected device as connected.

I confirmed this with all my devices that got Wifi (My new Android phone, my old bada phone, my Win10 tablet and my Win10 notebook).

Now to what happend: There are two main events in the last couple days that could maybe have triggered it. First the router has changed it's place (the difference is about half a meter and the router even gained distance to any metal) and I installed the new firmware (stock from Asus). Since I thought maybe there is a bug in the firmware I tried going back to the previous firmware but that did not change a thing.

I'm clueless how it can happen that it can connect to the dchp and after that is shut out from the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always factory reset routers after firmware changes, especially any fallback to prior version.

The ISP/gateway modem is? I have stepped-in to admin cable modems and found all customers WiFi clients in the parental or general block list of the modem. Win10 will mis-identify this condition as DNS error.

Comment: I hoped to avoid the factory reset but because noone else had an answer I reset my router last evening and it worked. I still don't like to spend half an hour each time I install a new firmware but it seems there is no choice.